# unrecognized selector sent to instance setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock using cargo bay

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to use CargoBay on my iOS project(ver. 5.1 >~),
for now a simple test project.

this is the code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[CargoBay sharedManager] setPaymentQueueUpdatedTransactionsBlock:^(SKPaymentQueue *queue, NSArray *transactions) {
        NSLog(@"Updated Transactions: %@", transactions);
        SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = transactions[0];
        NSData *receipt = [transaction transactionReceipt];
        NSLog(@"%@", receipt);

        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"https://mydomain/verify"];


        if (receipt) {
            [[CargoBay sharedManager] verifyTransactionWithMethod:@"POST" endpoint:url receipt:receipt password:@"aaa" success:^(NSDictionary *responseObject) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }];
        }
   }];

   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:[CargoBay sharedManager]];


   return YES;
}
```

but receiving this message just after the startup:

```
2013-08-13 21:41:15.357 TestCargoBay[8357:907] -[AFJSONRequestOperation  setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20093b70
2013-08-13 21:41:15.359 TestCargoBay[8357:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AFJSONRequestOperation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20093b70'
```

the message points to the cargobay

```
[requestOperation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock ...
```

code.

Have I make something wrong?

My Podfile is

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'AFNetworking',  '1.3.1'
pod 'CargoBay', '~> 0.3'
```

At last, my time programming in Cocoa is short.

Thank you,

Luiz

**Update**

The problem is that I installed the CargoBay and AFNetworking using cocoapods.
the AFNetworking prefix file(*.pch) are not recognized by xcode for now, I put the Pods-AFNetworking-prefix.pch content in the cargo bay file and works.

Thank You.

Comment: This error comes only when function name is not found or it is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you Lucas for the edition.

It's look my project have some think wrong, thank you Samkit, I will
check and post the result.

My best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Using AFNetworking version 1.2.0 or below should solve this issue.